# Can Selenium alone be used to automate the testing of an Intranet Web portal where the links on the portal are directed to SAP application

Tags: selenium

Can Selenium alone be used to automate the testing of an Intranet Web portal where the links on the portal are directed to SAP application.Portal works on IE and SAP application on Window OS only.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://seleniumsimplified.com/2016/01/can-i-use-selenium-webdriver-to-automate-a-windows-desktop-application/) page.

Comment: You can run selenium test in EI explorer, however, ability of selenium limited to working with browser's HTML,CSS ,JavaScript (Most common components of websites) If you planning to test with Selenium  against different technologies, you should consider other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest terms, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is a free (open source) automated testing suite for web applications across different browsers and platforms.

Inorder to use *Selenium* to automate the testing of an *Intranet Web Portal* you have to use either of the Selenium bindings among [java](/questions/tagged/java), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), etc.

Ideally, *Selenium* would be able to do each and every task hosted by an *Web Application*. If the concerned *SAP Application Portal* as of now supports [ie](/questions/tagged/ie), it can be well automated through *Selenium* irrespective of whether it is hosted in a Windows/Linux box.